# Table view batch updates while scrolling

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I've built a pagination mechanism for my table view so when the user scrolls to the last row in section the app loads additional content if possible. When additional content gets loaded, I perform a batch update on my table view like this:

```swift
guard
    let sectionIndex = self.sections.firstIndex(of: .itemsSection),
    !loadedItems.isEmpty
else { break }

let previousNumberOfRows = self.tableView.numberOfRows(inSection: sectionIndex)
let additionalIndexPaths = self.generateIndexPaths(
    startIndex: previousNumberOfRows,
    count: loadedItems.count,
    section: sectionIndex
)

self.tableView.performBatchUpdates({
    self.items.append(contentsOf: loadedItems)
    self.tableView.insertRows(at: additionalIndexPaths, with: .automatic)
}, completion: nil)
```

and here's a function that generates index paths to insert new rows at:

```swift
private func generateIndexPaths(startIndex: Int, count: Int, section: Int) -> [IndexPath] {
    var indexPaths: [IndexPath] = []
    for row in startIndex..<startIndex + count {
        indexPaths.append(IndexPath(row: row, section: section))
    }
    return indexPaths
}
```

It works perfectly fine until the update happens while table view is scrolling. Additional content is getting loaded so fast that the scroll animation have no time to finish. It starts to jump and additional cells pop with a broken animation. Since my table view uses `UITableView.automaticDimension`, I thought it was because of the wrong estimated height for newly created cells, so I implemented `tableView(_:estimatedHeightForRowAt:) -> CGFloat` method and gave those cells a pretty accurate height value. But it didn't help fixing the jumps. After trying all possible `UITableView.RowAnimation` fitting my need, I decided to completely disable the update animation. Here's how I'm currently updating the table view:

```swift
self.items.append(contentsOf: loadedItems)
UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(false)
self.tableView.insertRows(at: additionalIndexPaths, with: .none)
UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(true)
```

This approach gets rid of the update animation and at the same time introduces another problem: it feels like the table view is unresponsive during the update animation, like if I set `isUserInteractionEnabled = false` for a second. So what is the best way to update the table view with new rows with no animation and jumps? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: The best approach is to implement `UITableViewDataSourcePrefetching`. Here is a good resource to learn to do that: [link](https://www.raywenderlich.com/5786-uitableview-infinite-scrolling-tutorial)